# How to generate power law noise (colored noise) in Julia given an exponent?

Tags: r, julia

Is there an equivalent function in Julia that does the same as the R language function TK95? This function generates colored noise (noise with a power law in Fourier spectra) just by receiving the exponent of the power law.

Documentation of TK95: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/RobPer/html/TK95.html

I already know the function `rand(RedGaussian(size))` from SignalAnalysis package which does what I want, but generates only for the exponent equal to 2 and I need it to generate for any exponent value.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic since it's asking for a function/package, rather than asking how to solve it.  The source code for `RobPer::TK95` is only 7 lines long (set up a power-law sequence in Fourier space and inverse-transform it): that's something you should be able to implement in Julia fairly easily? https://juliapackages.com/c/fft

Comment: There is a function in PowerLaws.jl that allows you to set the alpha:  see con_powerlaw(alfa,xmin) in that package. To duplicate the values in TK95 you may need to use the fft method above though.